# How do I configure a Salesforce Connector in Azure Logic Apps to trigger on select field modifications instead of all fields?

Tags: salesforce, azure-logic-apps

Currently with our integration we have a Salesforce Connector in Azure Logic Apps, and we only want the logic app to fire when any one of a select fields are actually modified.  We have about 200 fields on the Account object and we don't need the trigger to fire on all the fields.

I have tried both the Select Query and the Filter Query parameters and from what I was able to test it doesn't do what we need.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Filter query just means (from what I can understand) we would only filter on certain criteria, much like a trigger condition.

I thought maybe the Select filter would work but the LA doesn't even fire when updated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sPcK.png)

UPDATE: I tried the first solution that was provided and the trigger condition in this case doesn't work as listed.  When I check the trigger history it is providing this additional error that the "contains" expression requires 2 parameters.

Unable to process template language expressions for trigger 'When_a_record_is_modified' at line '1' and column '14549': 'The template language function 'contains' expects two parameters : the collection of items to search within and the object to find within the collection. The function was invoked with '1' parameter(s). Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#contains for usage details.'.

Here is the trigger condition expression I had used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecApx.png)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you can use `Trigger Conditions` from the settings where the flow gets triggered based on the condition. Below is something how a trigger condition should look like.

```
@or(contains(triggerBody(),'<FIELD1>'),contains(triggerBody(),'<FIELD2>')...)
```

[image]

Sample expression in my logic app

```
@or(contains(triggerBody(),'Name'),contains(triggerBody(),'Id'),contains(triggerBody(),'Phone'))
```

The above expression makes the logic app trigger only when the mentioned fields are present.

[image]

Comment: How did I miss that, we have trigger conditions for other things but I didn't even think to use the contains() to focus on just those fields we want.  I'll run a few tests in our dev environment. This has been very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @spt Apologies, thank you for the nudge!

Comment: @SPT actually I just tried it on just the account name and it didn't work.  It triggered correctly when I updated the name, but I updated the language to make sure and it still fired.

This is the expression I'm using to just test it: 
@contains(triggerBody(),'Name')

Comment: @Zartan Can you add what is the response for your trigger

Comment: Unable to process template language expressions for trigger 'When_a_record_is_modified' at line '1' and column '14549': 'The template language function 'contains' expects two parameters : the collection of items to search within and the object to find within the collection. The function was invoked with '1' parameter(s). Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#contains for usage details.'.